# Pandas datetime isn't the same as unix time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert a pandas df's time series column which contains Unix time stamp to a datetime object. When I try to use online tools to see the real datetime it works perfectly fine. However, when I pass it to the pandas `to_datetime` it converts everything wrongly.

#### My df:

| date |
| --- |
| 1680524178283156 |
| 1680524178283542 |
| 1680524178284691 |
| 1680524178289810 |

the code is just a one-liner:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=True)
df.head()
```

#### The pandas output:

| date |
| --- |
| 1970-01-20 10:48:44.178283156 |
| 1970-01-20 10:48:44.178283542 |
| 1970-01-20 10:48:44.178284691 |
| 1970-01-20 10:48:44.178289810 |

The real dates while checking online (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) are quite recent. Such as `Mon Apr 03 2023 12:16:18 GMT+0000` for the first timestamp in the df above. Also the digits looks quite huge for Pandas datetime to convert if I try to play around other methods. Sometime, I also get error like `OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the date by `1_000_000` and then convert to date:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] / 1_000_000, unit='s', origin='unix')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                           date
0 2023-04-03 12:16:18.283155968
1 2023-04-03 12:16:18.283542016
2 2023-04-03 12:16:18.284691200
3 2023-04-03 12:16:18.289809920
```

---

OR: Convert from micro-seconds:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='us')
```

Comment: why this division operation? Could you kindly explain this solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NirajDPandey The value you've got, e.g. `1680524178283156` is not in seconds but in micro-seconds. So I divide it by 1000000 in my first example (to convert it from seconds).

Comment: Why not pass unit='ms'?

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the given integer timestamps  to pandas timestamps using `pd.to_datetime` function, and then use `dt.strftime` method to format the timestamps to get the desired output.

Here is the example

```
import pandas as pd

timestamps = [1680524178283156, 1680524178283542, 1680524178284691, 1680524178289810]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': timestamps})

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='us')
df['FormattedTimestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT+0000')

print(df)
```

output:

```
Timestamp                 FormattedTimestamp
0 2023-04-03 12:16:18.283156  Mon Apr 03 2023 12:16:18 GMT+0000
1 2023-04-03 12:16:18.283542  Mon Apr 03 2023 12:16:18 GMT+0000
2 2023-04-03 12:16:18.284691  Mon Apr 03 2023 12:16:18 GMT+0000
3 2023-04-03 12:16:18.289810  Mon Apr 03 2023 12:16:18 GMT+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your column to the correct format:

```
df = df.assign(date=df.loc[:, 'date'].astype(dtype='datetime64[us]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear up some unit confusion.

POSIX timestamps are usually measured in seconds; if you say "UNIX time", the expectation is that the value is in seconds.

Some systems do use other units; Javascript, for instance, uses milliseconds.

It appears that Pandas by default uses nanoseconds.

Meanwhile, your data seems to be given in microseconds.

So you have to do something to your value to convert it depending on what tool you want to use. For pandas, multiply by 1000 to go from microseconds to nanoseconds. For a standard POSIX timestamp, divide by 1,000,000 to go from microseconds to seconds:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> ts = 1680524178283156
>>> pd.to_datetime(ts * 1000)
Timestamp('2023-04-03 12:16:18.283156')
>>> dt.utcfromtimestamp(ts / 1_000_000)
datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 12, 16, 18, 283156)
```

Alternatively, Pandas does let you specify the unit in the call instead of doing the arithmetic yourself:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='us')
Timestamp('2023-04-03 12:16:18.283156')
```